# Remove filename from cell address

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have this formula:

```
=IFERROR(CELL
           ("address",
            INDEX(
              INDIRECT($Q61),
              SUMPRODUCT(
                (INDIRECT($O$5)=$B$1)*(INDIRECT($O$6)=$B$2)*
                (INDIRECT($O$3)=$B$3)*(INDIRECT($O$7)=B$4)*ROW(INDIRECT($O$8))
              )-5
            )
           ),""
         )
```

which returns a cell address:

```
'[CILT Audit Report - 2018 Week 17.xlsm]Data'!$AO$152
```

How do I truncate the file name and the sheet name to get an address in the form AO152?  I will be using that address in VBA to get the hyperlink for that address.

Answer (score 0):

Say your formula *(in cell **A1**)* returns:

```
'[CILT Audit Report - 2018 Week 17.xlsm]Data'!$AO$152
```

In VBA:

```
Sub GetAddress()
    Dim s As String, arr
    s = Range("A1").Value
    arr = Split(s, "!")
    MsgBox Replace(arr(1), "$", "")
End Sub
```

[image]